Does the classical Hamiltonian of the radiation field as $\sum (C_k)^2 k^2$ require constant polarization?
I tried to derive the Hamiltonian of the classical radiation field following this reference.
But I made a different approach for the polarization, introducing a phase in the generic solution of the wave equation:
$$A^j = C^je^i(\vec k \cdot \vec r - \omega_k t + \theta^j)$$
As the phases can be different for each component of $\vec A$, I believe it allows any type of polarization.
However when getting the B-field as $\nabla \times \vec A$, and integrating $B^2=B_x^2+B_y^2+B_z^2$ to get the second part of the Hamiltonian, it is only possible to get $\sum k^2C^2$ if all phases are equal. Otherwise, there are terms involving the cosines between this angles.
Is there something wrong with my approach? Does the final form of the classical Hamiltonian as $\sum k^2C^2$ require a constant, (not a circular or elliptic) polarization?
Edit:
Well, if the condition of orthogonality between $\vec A$ and $\vec k$ can be expressed by:
$$(k_jC^je^{i\theta^j})(k_jC^je^{-i\theta^j})=0$$ I can get rid of the trigonometric functions. It makes sense because at a given point the direction of $\vec C$ is a function of the phases. But it is not the usual "dot product equals zero".

This is strange, since $|\vec B_k | \propto | \vec k \times \vec A_k| = |\vec k| |\vec A_k|$ since $\vec k$ and $\vec A_k$ made an angle of $\pi/2$ no matter the polarization. Is it isn't enough to consider the components of $\vec A_k$ as complex numbers?

@Ruffolo Please see my edit.
